# Angularjs passing checkbox value from one controller to other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make one application where i want to pass checkbox value from one controller to other. I have two panels (left and right) as shown below , and separate controllers for them, lets say leftC and rightC.

[image: application snapshot]

Things are working fine for left and right panels and i am able to generate graphs as well. Now i want the graphs to be appear only if the corresponding checkbox is checked and hide if it is unchecked. How can i achieve this functionality in angularjs. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the $rootScope in this case.Take a boolean value in root scope and change the flag on checking of box. And use that flag in ng-if.